# How to get published at a young age?

Tags: publishing, young-author

I am currently 10 years old and am writing a story based off of the short story I wrote back in first grade. I am still trying to decide what to call the book but it is about a group of five young girls who have a horse riding group who one day decide to go into a part of the mountains on horseback that is very treacherous. Later on one of the girls gets injured and the girls have to find a new member for the team because they have a big competition coming up.

I want to know how to get published.

Comment: Maybe you would find this similar question useful? https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/18591/is-it-okay-to-publish-a-book-at-a-young-age

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Kenzie*! I edited your question a bit as we don't allow any suggestion questions here. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Hi Kenzie, I have the accepted answer on this similar question, about publishing as a teenager. Click here: https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/33239/26047

Comment: I can not answer this question today, but (years ago in a country that no longer exists) I was able get published at a little older age. What might be helpful is to look for an organization or periodical that encourages young authors to contribute. A short story is not likely to be published as a separate book, so an editor would have to include it in a collection of other, perhaps similar stories.

Answer (score 6):

One of the other answers might have been a bit harsh and would lead more established writers to mutter sarcastically "wish I'd thought of that", but there's something useful in it - it sounds like you're thinking ahead to publication before the book is finished.

While you'll want to consider your intended audience during writing and editing, an important step is the book. I've worked in manufacturing, and while market research is significant it's best to have a product when considering a sales strategy.

At this point I'd concentrate on writing the book. Worst case : no publisher takes it. This still leaves you with something you've achieved, and there are other options like self publication or returning to it later when you're more experienced.

You're a lot of the way there. You've established characters [the girls], a premise [the riding group and competition] and a plot. You've asked other people for advice.

(As an aside - and I'm at risk of going off-topic here - the character that fascinates me is the one who was injured and won't be able to join the competition. I hope you'll cover her views.)

It looks like you're doing it right so far.

Answer (score 0):

As [the answers to another question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/18591/is-it-okay-to-publish-a-book-at-a-young-age) has explained, age is largely irrelevant for getting published.

As for how to get published:

- Write a good book.
- Submit it to an agent or publisher.

Both steps have been addressed by countless questions on this site. The site search (at the top of each page) will help you find them.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. A reference to a previous answer is not an answer; and the "advice" given here is snide and unhelpful, especially to a 10 year old asking a sincere question.

Comment: I disagree with the above two comments.  This does provide an answer: it states two simple steps to take in order to get published, and that the specific circumstances in this question don't really make any significant difference to the process.  It's short, but it answers the question.